# How to convert scientific notation stored as string to int in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe in pandas that is storing scientific notations as strings. I want to convert them strings to integers. But i am running into an issue that is best described by the code snippet below

Expected behavior:

```
print(int(float('9.01E+26')))
output:
901000000000000035886465024
```

Behaviour i am getting:

```
a = pd.Series({'a':'9.01E+26'})
print(a.astype(float).astype(int))
output:
a   -9223372036854775808
dtype: int64
```

How do i go about achieving the expected behavior?

Comment: Interesting. I assume this is on Windows (edit: nevermind, you would have got `dtype: int32` if it was). The default `int` type used by `numpy` is 32 bit on Windows, but indeed this overflows `np.int64` too. It's not clear how to get python `int` behaviour that doesn't overflow

Comment: In fact, I'm suspecting that you simply cannot work with integers of this size in numpy. You'd either need floats or work with python list comprehensions instead. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: .apply would be the way to go then i guess?

Comment: That will give you `OverflowError: int too big to convert`. There must be some interim dtype going from `np.float` to a regular Python `int` that simply blocks the conversion

Comment: ohh that so? i was thinking that  since int(float('9.01E+26')) works... .apply would work too

Comment: `my_list = [int(float(item)) for item in a.values.tolist()]` will work, though. But now you've lost all of numpy/pandas and are just back to a regular old list. Is having the `int` dtype worth this?

Comment: No it isnt. In my specific use case, i could easily help myself by going around in a lot of ways. was just curious

Comment: @roganjosh: What gives you  `OverflowError`? I can run `a.apply(float).apply(int)` which will happily do the conversion but the `dtype` will of course be `object` since it is not a (`numpy`) native datatype.

Comment: @JohanL it comes from `File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1165, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects`, presumably coming up from C because the line it refers to is in (near enough the same code but different line numbers, since I'm not on latest version) [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1968)

Comment: @JohanL I had been trying to pin the issue down better because it's not clear to me _what_ the interim object would have been that overflowed, but I chased the issue back to Cython and C, neither of which I have a great understanding on. Let me dig out the exact line again.

Comment: @JohanL ok, I'm on 0.20.3 and the closest I can get is [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx#L1079). If the line numbers are exactly the same, then it's [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx#L1165) line that throws the error. There are no such source files left on my PC to confirm exactly. Seems there's been a lot of refactoring again with the later versions :)

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I am at 0.24.2 and there `inference.pyx` does not even exist (at least not in that folder) so I guess updating to a newer version removes the exception.